# Error en código con if y else if

Tags: javascript, condiciones, else

Tengo este código que cada vez que lo ejecuto me da error y no se por qué, básicamente lo que quiero es que se introduzcan 2 números y que x sea la operación que se haga a esos números, cualquier ayuda se agradece mucho.

```
var a, b, x, soma, media, listagem;

a = Number(prompt("a?"));
x = Numberprompt("operaçao?");
b = Number(prompt("b?"));
{
if x = "m"
    listagem = CSSMathMax( a, b);
if x = "M"
    listagem = CSSMathMin( a, b);
if x = "E"
    alert("ERROR");
if x = "+"
    listagem = a + b;
if x = "-"
    listagem = a - b;
if x = "x"
    listagem = a * b;
if x = "/"
    listagem = a / b;
else if
    alert("ERROR, VALOR INVALIDO");
}
alert(listagem);
```

Comment: el codigo lo hice en la consola de google

Answer (score 8):

Comencemos por el principio, [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML) es un lenguaje de etiquetas, **no tiene lógica**.

Lo que tienes es [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript); además `java != javascript`, o lo que es lo mismo, [Java](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n)) es un lenguaje y Javascript otro, lo único que tienen en común es la palabra *java*, el resto es muy diferente.

Javascript tiene la siguiente estructura a la hora de declarar funciones o variables:

```
var/let nombreVariable = tuValor;
```

`var` es para uso global, `let` para un uso determinado dentro de la función.

```
function NombreTuFuncion(parametros){
    //lógica
}
```

Ahora paso a analizar tu código:

- `Numberprompt("operaçao?")` ¿Esto existe en javascript?
- ¿Por qué usas una { para empezar la lógica?
- `if(//condición){//haz aquí si la condición es correcta} elseif(//condicionSiLaPrimeraNo){//codigo} else{ //esto si no lo es }`

Lo que creo que has intentado pero no has realizado correctamente:

```js
var a, b, x, soma, media, listagem;
//Variables númericas
a = Number(prompt("Primer valor:"));
b = Number(prompt("Segundo valor:"));
//Variable de texto
x = prompt("Tipo de operación:");

//switch para seleccionar la opcion en cada caso (ahorra uso de memoria y tiempo de ejecución)
switch(x){
  case "m":
    listagem = CSSMathMax( a, b);
    break;
  case "M":
    listagem = CSSMathMin( a, b);
    break;
  case "E":
    alert("ERROR");
    break;
  case "+":
    listagem = (a + b);
    break;
  case "-":
    listagem = (a - b);
    break;
  case "*":
    listagem = (a * b);
    break;
  case "//":
    listagem = (a / b);
    break;
}

alert(listagem);
```

## Edición snippet con html

```js
var a, b, x, listagem;

function Calcular(){

  a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var e = document.getElementById("operador");
  x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
  
  //switch para seleccionar la opcion en cada caso (ahorra uso de memoria y tiempo de ejecución)
  switch(x){
    case "m":
      listagem = CSSMathMax( a, b);
      break;
    case "M":
      listagem = CSSMathMin( a, b);
      break;
    case "E":
      alert("ERROR");
      break;
    case "+":
      listagem = (a + b);
      break;
    case "-":
      listagem = (a - b);
      break;
    case "*":
      listagem = (a * b);
      break;
    case "//":
      listagem = (a / b);
      break;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("res").value = listagem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Primer valor:</label>
  <input type="text" id="a" name="a">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Operador:</label>
  <select id="operador">
    <option value="m">Minimo</option>
    <option value="M">Maximo</option>
    <option value="+">Sumar</option>
    <option value="-">Restar</option>
    <option value="*">Multiplicar</option>
    <option value="/">Dividir</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Segundo valor:</label>
  <input type="text" id="b" name="b">
</div>
<div>
 <button type="button" onClick="Calcular()">Calcular!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Resultado:</label>
  <input type="text" id="res" name="res" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: ese codigo se puede usar tal cual en el lenguaje html? porque el codigo lo necesito para un cuadro de texto dentro de una pagina, pero igual graciasss

Comment: Te hago una edición introduciendo los campos desde un formulario

Comment: @Chrogued Si esta u otra respuesta ha sido valida, te invito a que pulses el check de la izquierda para que otros puedan ver cual ha sido la respuesta que te ha ayudado y aparte ganaras algo mas de reputación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, subi otro donde ya implemente el codigo a html y creo que funciona pero no logro que al darle a calcular muestre el resultado.

Comment: En el ejemplo con html, puedes ver que lo hace `document.getElementById("res").value = listagem;` es lo que pinta el valor

Answer (score 4):

```
var a, b, x, soma, media, listagem;

a = Number(prompt("a?"));
x = Number(prompt("operaçao?");
b = Number(prompt("b?"));

if(x == "m"){
    listagem = CSSMathMax( a, b);
}

if(x == "M"){
    listagem = CSSMathMin( a, b);
}

if(x == "E"){
    alert("ERROR");
}

if(x == "+"){
    listagem = a + b;
}

if(x == "-"){
    listagem = a - b;
}

if(x == "x"){
    listagem = a * b;
}

if(x == "/"){
    listagem = a / b;
}

else{
    alert("ERROR, VALOR INVALIDO");
}

alert(listagem);
```

El problema es de sintaxis 100%, no del portugués. Así estaría correcto.

Comment: eres mi nuevo dios, GRACIAS

Comment: me da un error al final del todo, dice Unexpected end of input, que puede ser?

Comment: Hay varios IF con la condición incorrecta: = en lugar de ==

Comment: Si cierto, perdona, el agua no me dejaba ver bien del todo. Ahora edito.

Answer (score 4):

Asi no te aparecerán errores.
Pero también puedes usar la sentencia switch

```
var a, b, x, soma, media, listagem;

a = Number(prompt("a?"));
x = prompt("operaçao?");
b = Number(prompt("b?"));
switch (x){
    case "m":
    listagem = CSSMathMax( a, b);
    break;
    case "M":
    listagem = CSSMathMin( a, b);
    break;
    case "E":
    console.log("ERROR");
    break;
    case "+":
    listagem = a + b;
    break;
    case "-":
    listagem = a - b;
    break;
    case "x":
    listagem = a * b;
    break;
    case "/":
    listagem = a / b;
    break;
    default:
    console.log("ERROR, VALOR INVALIDO");
}
```

Para este caso creo que es la más apropiada. Recorre todas las opciones y si ninguna es la tecleada envía el mensaje de error.
**EDITADO**
X no puede ser un número, debe ser x = prompt("operaçao?"), ahora si es un carácter.

Comment: no me dio ningun error pero el resultado siempre es "error, valor invalido" independiente de las variabes :(

Comment: Es porque la variable x no es númerica